# Temporarily delay page scrolling with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have so far create a page that when scrolling down and a container div is reached, a number of divs within it begin to scroll horizontally along the page. My problem is that I want the page to stop scrolling vertically until all the divs have scrolled all the way along to the left then for the page to begin scrolling vertically again. Essentially, the user scrolls down to the container, horizontal scrolling of the divs are triggered, once across the page, begin scrolling down again. This is what I have so far:

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  $("#service1, #service2, #service3").css({
    "left": windowWidth
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#service1, #service2, #service3").css({
      "left": windowWidth - $(window).scrollTop()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#hero {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#about {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#services {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 900px;
  margin-bottom: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#service1 {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 34px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  ;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}

#service2 {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 34px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  ;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 1300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}

#service3 {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 34px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  ;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 2600px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero"></div>

<div id="about"></div>

<div id="services">
  <div id="service1"></div>
  <div id="service2"></div>
  <div id="service3"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope I have been clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMMouseScroll` event for check the scroll and block this with detect and replace event. Please try below. I have block vertical scroll when scroll arrive in third section and reactive when is arrive a size defined left. You can modify with what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 $("#service1, #service2, #service3").css({
  "left": windowWidth
 });

 function scrollHorizontally(e) {
  e = window.event || e;
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  $(document).scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft()-(delta*40)); 
  $("body").scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft()-(delta*40)); 
  e.preventDefault();
 }

 $('html').on ('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
  var sens = e.originalEvent.detail;
  var lastDivTop = ($(window).scrollTop() - $("#services").offset().top)
  var lastDivLeft = ($(window).scrollLeft() - $("#services").offset().left)
  if (sens < 0) { //scroll Up
   if(lastDivLeft > 0 && lastDivTop < 100 ){
    scrollHorizontally(e)
        $(window).scrollTop($("#services").offset().top)
   }
  } else if (sens > 0) { //scroll down
   if(lastDivTop > 0 && lastDivLeft < 1500){
    scrollHorizontally(e)
        $(window).scrollTop($("#services").offset().top)
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```css
#hero {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#about {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#services {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 900px;
  margin-bottom: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#service1 {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 34px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  ;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}

#service2 {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 34px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  ;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 1300px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}

#service3 {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 34px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  ;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 2600px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero"></div>

<div id="about"></div>

<div id="services">
  <div id="service1"></div>
  <div id="service2"></div>
  <div id="service3"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't seem to work. I have tried and nothing happens, the horizontal divs just don't appear. Any reason this may not work? Thanks. (Sorry for any ignorance, I only know HTML and CSS so far, not JS/jQuery.)